# Can't create Views

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I installed Views module for Drupal 6 and tried to create a view with a Page display but I can't save or preview it. All I can see are these warnings:

```
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_style_default::options() should be compatible with views_object::options() in C:\My\Site\Path\test6\sites\all\modules\views\plugins\views_plugin_style_default.inc on line 13.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_row::options_validate() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_validate(&$form, &$form_state) in C:\My\Site\Path\test6\sites\all\modules\views\plugins\views_plugin_row.inc on line 24.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_row::options_submit() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_submit(&$form, &$form_state) in C:\My\Site\Path\test6\sites\all\modules\views\plugins\views_plugin_row.inc on line 24.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_validate() should be compatible with views_handler::options_validate($form, &$form_state) in C:\My\Site\Path\test6\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_filter.inc on line 26.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_submit() should be compatible with views_handler::options_submit($form, &$form_state) in C:\My\Site\Path\test6\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_filter.inc on line 26.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter_term_node_tid::value_validate() should be compatible with views_handler_filter::value_validate($form, &$form_state) in C:\My\Site\Path\test6\sites\all\modules\views\modules\taxonomy\views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc on line 6.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your browser for availability of Jquery when your drupal site pages load. Specially your views pages. What version of Jquery is your Drupal site using. I have faced this before and was sorted out by first ensuring availability of correct compatible version of jquery.

This might have happened if you tried to update your Jquery version through Jquery_update module. Can you please check it and reply accordingly. I am sure this is very much solvable.

Comment: I found this in the html page header tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/jquery.js?N"></script>` and there is jquery version 1.2.6